# django relationships into a cbv

Tags: django, django-models

I have this two models:

```
class MenuGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class MenuProduct(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ingredients = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0.0)
    group = models.ForeignKey(MenuGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to get all the records of MenuGroup with all the MenuProduct records related.
Template side i need to have structure like this:

```
 {% for group in menugroups %}

...

{% product in group.menuproducts %}
```

How to express this into a Django CBV view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything, Django gives you that functionality already. The only thing to change is that the default accessor is `<modelname>_set`, and it's a Manager; so:

```
{% for product in group.menuproduct_set.all %}
```

Comment: thank you very much it works for me. I don't think that this was so easy in django